# Expand summary block to full width if there no items in queue

Tags: feature-request, design, review

If a queue has items to review, it looks fine:

> [image]

But if there are no items in queue, the description looks bad.

> [image]

This block basically consists of 2 blocks:

```
<div>
    <div class="review-summary">
    </div>
    <div class="review-actions-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know the best solution, but even if you just change width of `review-summary` flex box to `100%` it will look much better:

> [image]